# How to convert respectively four column to date formatting at MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, date, converters

Excel file(104976x10) includes large data.

- A column: Time (unit year)
- B column: Year
- C column: Day of the year
- D column: Hour
- E column: Minute
- and others including values

I would like to convert column which begins with B column until E column to date format like 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM'.

Example for the data:

```
1998,41655251   1998    152   1   0   12,5  12,0    11,8    11,9    12,0
```

I would like to do date instead of 2-th, 3-th, 4-th and 5-th columns.

```
1998,41655251   01/06/1998 01:00    12,5  12,0  11,8  11,9  12,0
```

or

```
1998,41655251   01/06/1998 01:00  1998  152   1   0   12,5  12,0    11,8    11,9    12,0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.
Matlab has two types of date-format:

1. [datetime](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html), introduced in 2014b.
2. [datenum](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html), introcuced in long ago (before 2006b), it is basically a double precision value giving the number of days from January 0, 0000.

I think the best way is to use datetime, and give it the year, month, day, hour and minute values like this:

`t=datetime(1998,0,152,1,0,0)`

> t= '01-May-1998 01:00:00'

As you can see the days automatically overflow into the months. But I end up 1st of may, not 1st of june like in your example.

to change the format:

`t.Format='dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'`

> t= '01/05/1998 01:00'

to convert it to a string, you can simply use `string(t)`

This is an example that combines the above functions to read an xlsx file and writes a new one with the updated column.

```
data=xlsread('test.xlsx');
S = size(data);
t = datetime(data(:,2),0,data(:,3),data(:,4),data(:,5),0);
t.Format='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm';
data2=num2cell(data(:,1));
data2(:,2)=cellstr(string(t));
data2(:,3:S(2)-3)=num2cell(data(:,6:end));
xlswrite('test2.xlsx',data2);
```

Comment: Date format described t.Format but output format is like 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss'. I don't understand why it is not like 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM'?

Comment: capital M is month, small lettre m is minute. HH is 24 hours, hh is 12 hours. https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#buhzxmk-1-Format

Comment: I would suggest using `readtable` instead of `xlsread`, causes a lot less headaches in general.

Comment: Why is that? I did some digging. `\toolbox\shared\spreadsheet\+matlab\+io\+spreadsheet\+internal` has `readSpreadsheetFile.m` and  `\toolbox\matlab\iofun\private` has eight files that start with xls, but one of them is `xlsreadXLSX.m` I'm surprised there are so many options in Matlab for this.

Comment: Good question, as far as I know `readtable` was introduced in R2013b as an improved function for reading data from spreadsheets. I believe that internally the function *still* uses `xlsread`, however it wraps it in a function that generally speaking is less error prone.